# 1 second gap within each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to execute a function inside a each() function every 1 second. How can I do this?

```
$('.items:visible').each(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    executeNow(i, s, id);
    count++;
    if(count==total){
       ///do something
    }
});
```

Basically I need to have a 1 second gap each time the `executeNow();` is called inside this each() function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a simple *run-away-timer* yourself, like so:

```
var set = $('.items:visible').get();

(function loop( elem ) {
    executeNow( elem );

    if( set.length ) {
        setTimeout( function() {
            loop( set.shift() );
        }, 1000 );
    }
}( set.shift() ));
```

That way, timers cannot interfere or overlap. Classical you would just call a `setTimeout` with increasing timeout values, but the solution above is cleaner and more reliable.

Comment: _Interesting approach ;)_

Comment: It really should be standard. Most people don't understand how `setTimeout` and `setInterval` works internally. Execution order and timing is not guaranteed. Using a run-away-timer you know for sure that a) execution order is consistent and b) calls can never overlap. This is not the case using `setTimeout` with different values, especially if a lot is going on your site due to scripts.

Comment: When I posted this question, I did not think that passing arguments would case issues. I see `executeNow( elem )` Can you show how to pass arguments within your method?  I have edited my question with my actual requirment.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer it's the cleanest and most solid solution imo.

Comment: Yes you can pass any arguments you want into either the next loop-call and/or to `executeNow` function.

Comment: @jAndy – Any use-case where solution I have provided will fail or order may go wrong ?

Comment: It cannot really "fail", but it's very possible that like 2 calls with be very accurate by 1000ms and the next 4 calls will be called very fast successively for instance. Using `setTimeout` will just put that function into the browsers *UI Thread* and if there are other long-running or intense scripts going on, this can very possibly interfere. So it will work as quick&dirty solution, but in any solid scenario, we want to use run-away-timers.

Comment: @Becky You can just call `executeNow( elem.id );` for instance, to pass the ID for the current element.

Answer (score 3):

First argument in [**`jQuery.each`**](https://api.jquery.com/each/) is `index` which could be used as multiplication factor for `setTimeout` *duration*

```
$('.items:visible').each(function(index) {
  setTimeout(executeNow, 1000 * (index + 1));
});
```

As `index` for first `iteration` will be `0`, `index + 1` is used!

To pass arguments while invoking `executeNow`,

```
$('.items:visible').each(function(index) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    executeNow(args....);
  }, 1000 * (index + 1));
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain (index + 1) ?

Comment: why (index + 1)? Delay should be between calls so first one should be called immediately. Super minor though and like your solution.

Comment: Can I pass arguments ? `setTimeout(executeNow(i,s), 1000 * (index + 1))`

Comment: @Becky You can make usage of `.bind()` or just put in an anonymous function and call `exectuteNow( i, s );` from within.

Comment: @Downvoter, I failed to understand the reason for _downvote_, your _comment_ is precious for me!

Comment: I see that passing arguments is not possible with your suggestion. I did not think that would be an issue when I originally posted this question. Please see my edit.

Comment: When I do `setTimeout(function() { var id = this.id; executeNow(args....);` I get an error. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null`.

Comment: `this.id` has null value

Comment: Check the value of `this`, it is not what you are expecting... Try this=> https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/d4bwo3ae/1/

Comment: I see. As in my post, how can I get the ID of the element in the each() funtion along with your setTimeout() method?

Answer (score 0):

try this simple approach

```
var ms = 1000;
var runningMS = 0;
$('.items:visible').each(function(){
    setTimeout( function(){
        executeNow();
    }, runningMS );
    runningMS += ms;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.queue()`, `$.map()`, `.promise()`

```js
var colors = ["blue", "green", "red"];

function executeNow(el, args, next) {
  el.css("color", args)
  setTimeout(next, 1000)
}

function queueComplete(elems) {
  console.log(elems);
  alert("complete");
}

var items = $(".items:visible")

items.queue("items", $.map(items, function(item, index) {
  return function(next) {
    executeNow($(item), colors[index], next);
  }
}))
.dequeue("items").promise("items")
.then(queueComplete)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
<div class="items">a</div>
<div class="items">b</div>
<div class="items">c</div>
```